# How to invoke tauri api in Blazor wasm?

Tags: javascript, c#, rust, blazor-webassembly, tauri

I am using TAURI + Blazor web assembly to make a desktop app. Now I need to add some native window features to my app, like maximize the window, etc. However, when I invoke a JavaScript function in the index.razor file, something cannot work right. There's some errors, but I don't not where they are.

[image: The main window with an error notification.]

My code in `js/scripts.js` is

```js
import { appWindow } from "@tauri-apps/api/window";

export async function ToggleWindowMax() {
  await appWindow.toggleMaximize();
}
```

And my code in `Pages/index.razor` is

```
@page "/"
@inject IJSRuntime JS

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>



<MudStack>
    <MudButton Class="pa-3 border-solid" Variant="Variant.Outlined" DisableRipple="true" OnClick="ToggleMax"
        Style="@($"color: {Colors.Purple.Accent3}; border-color:{Colors.Purple.Accent2}; border-width: 2px; border-radius: 9999px;")">
        @result
    </MudButton>

</MudStack>


@code {
    private IJSObjectReference? module;
    private string result = "Toggle Maximize";
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            module = await JS.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./js/scripts.js");
        }
    }

    private async Task ToggleMax()
    {
        await module.InvokeVoidAsync("ToggleWindowMax");
    }
}
```

I have added the needed yarn package with `yarn add @tauri-apps/api`. I need your help.

I tried to find the right ways to invoke some JavaScript functions, such as prompt or alert. However, I cannot invoke the Tauri api correctly.

Comment: This question is old.  I’m just looking into Tauri now so I am wholly unqualified to answer this question right now.  However, there is a GitHub repo with Blazor running under Tauri that might help.  https://github.com/rodiniz/TauriWithBlazor